# Why is GMSPolygon not responding to taps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, user-interface

I have my Google Map appearing in my ios app and my polygon being drawn on the map successfully with the following code in my view controller:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.886080, longitude: -122.137585, zoom: 7.0)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: screenWidth*0.03, y: 245, width: screenWidth*0.94, height: screenHeight*0.45), camera: camera)
self.view.addSubview(mapView)

let rect = GMSMutablePath()
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.886080, longitude: -122.137585))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.899356, longitude: -122.130203))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.900101, longitude: -122.104282))
rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.879644, longitude: -122.101192))
let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
polygon.fillColor = UIColor.flatWatermelonDark.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
polygon.strokeColor = .black
polygon.strokeWidth = 2
polygon.isTappable = true
polygon.map = mapView
```

I also am implementing the GMSMapViewDelegate in my view controller and have the following function as part of my view controller:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    print("Jesus loves you")
    print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")

}
```

It is my understanding that because I set the polygon variable's .isTappable value to true, when the polygon is tappend the delegate method should be called and print "Jesus loves you" and the overlay that was tapped. No such printing occurs when I tap the polygon though which implies the didTap delegate method is not being called. Am I missing something in my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a total idiot.

Was not setting the map view's delegate property to self in viewDidLoad.

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

Now the problem is solved!

Comment: haha, I'm looking for this too now add this line and my code works thanks